# Json to php

Tags: json, php

Как из этого?

> a:2:{s:6:"Тип";s:20:"квадробокс";s:37:"Размеры
> (Д х Ш х В, см)";s:5:"15x20";}

Сделать массив в нормальном виде?

Comment: по-моему это не json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция [unserialize](http://www.php.su/unserialize)

Применяем ее к входной строке, а к результату применяем json_encode().

Answer (score 0):

вам нужен unserialize